# Unresolved compilation while creating date object with long :Java

Tags: java

I tried the following code.

```
System.out.println(new Date(1268234290000));
```

It throws Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The literal 1268234290000 of type int is out of range
```

How to resolve?

Comment: I always wonder how it can be more difficult to write a question on [SO] instead of Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V the error into google first...

Comment: Firstly, don't try running code that doesn't compile anyway. Fix it before you try to run it.

Comment: This kind of asking question in discussion form always shows a healthy way of learning. Do not discourage- comment to @ppeterka66

Comment: @Pinky I disagree. This has been asked and answered [at least 3 times even here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+literal+of+type+int+is+out+of+range+), and I bet at least 1 million times at other places. **Give someone a fish, and he'll keep asking for it. Teach someone to fish, and he'll catch it himself...**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's a long value append `L`

```
 System.out.println(new Date(1268234290000L));
```

[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).