# Java time to the normal format

Tags: java, scala

I have Java time `1380822000000`. And I want to convert to something I can read:

```
import java.util.Date

object Ws1 {
  val a = new Date("1380822000000").toString()
}
```

causes an exception

```
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for detai
  ls
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:615)
    at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:272)
    at .<init>(<console>:9)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57
  )
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
  .java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:790)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:702)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:566)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scal
  a:867)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.
  scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:822)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.WorksheetRunner.main(WorksheetRunner.j
  ava:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57
  )
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
  .java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

How do I convert it to the normal human representation?

Comment: That number is not a "Java time". It is (apparently) a count of [milliseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) from [epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or do the better thing and use `org.jodatime`;

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

val timestamp = new DateTime(1380822000000L);
```

as you can see [**here**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), a miliseconds since EPOCH is already implemented.

Comment: Agreed mate :) but when needed.

Answer (score 6):

You should pass that number as a long integer to get desired result, string can be passed but that should be parse-able.

```
val a = new Date(1380822000000L).toString();
```

Look at the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) for more info.

Comment: [Won't compile. Can you please check once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025054/unresolved-compilation-while-creating-date-object-with-long-java/19025063#19025063)

Comment: Edited, I missed that _L_.

Comment: @Electrosa String can be passed, but that is deprecated.

Comment: @Masud But constructor Date(String) expects a human-readable string, for example, `"03/10/2013 5:35:37 PM"` would be OK. Also, this constructor is deprecated as you say.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting one warning :

> warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s);

Because `new Date(String)` has been deprecated.

Secondly , `new Date("1380822000000")`  is not valid `String` to convert in to `date`, because it is in `milli seconds` which is a `long` value.

You have to do this

```
 vav a= new Date(1380822000000L).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Examples, in Java syntax.

In UTC:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( Long.parseLong( "1380822000000" ) )
       .toString()
```

> 2013-10-03T17:40:00Z

In a particular time zone:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( Long.parseLong( "1380822000000" ) )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
       .toString()
```

> 2013-10-03T13:40:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

Localized:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( Long.parseLong( "1380822000000" ) )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
       .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                 .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) 
              )
```

>

## java.time

The notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar classes bundled with older versions of Java have now been supplanted by the new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

An Instant represents a moment on the timeline. A ZonedDateTime assigns a time zone to an Instant.

Be aware that java.time has a resolution of nanoseconds while the earlier frameworks have a granularity of milliseconds. You'll see below the method `ofEpochMilli` provided as a convenience, but java.time is not restricted to milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1380822000000L ) ;  // Note the "L" on the long integer literal.
```

If the input is a String, parse into a `long` integer value. See the [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-) static method.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( Long.parseLong( "1380822000000" ) ) ;
```

You can adjust into a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zone );
```

## Formats

That ZonedDateTime's `toString` method will generate a string representation of the date-time value in the format of the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Search StackOverflow for "formatter" to learn how to generate other strings.